# Transform an array of data by status

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I need to filter an array by property:

Here's the data, which I get from the server:

```
const mockResults = [
  {
    user: {
      firstName: '1',
      lastName: '1'
    },
    status: 'WRONG'
  },
  {
    user: {
      firstName: '2',
      lastName: '2'
    },
    status: 'WRONG'
  },
  {
    user: {
      firstName: '3',
      lastName: '3'
    },
    status: 'CORRECT'
  }
];
```

To display the data, I need to transform it to a required by ReactNative SectionList format:

```
const requiredFormat = [
  {
    status: 'WRONG',
    data: [{ user: {firstName: '1', lastName: '1'}}, { user: {firstName: '2', lastName: '2'}}],
  },
  {
    status: 'CORRECT',
    data: [{ user: {firstName: '3', lastName: '3'}}],
  },
];
```

Basically, the `mockResults` should be sorted by `status`. There can be maximum of 4 statuses: `correct, wrong, missed, chosen`. All these statuses should include all the data marked with them.

What is the right way to implement this?

I've tried to filter the array, but I'm stuck at this point:

```
const transformArray = mockResults.filter(item => {
  return {
    answerStatus: item.status,
    data: [item.user]
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may walk through the array (using [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method) and create new element of resulting array once you see there's no such with current `status` or append current element data if one exists:

```js
const mockResults = [{user:{firstName:'1',lastName:'1'},status:'WRONG'},{user:{firstName:'2',lastName:'2'},status:'WRONG'},{user:{firstName:'3',lastName:'3'},status:'CORRECT'}],

      result = mockResults.reduce((r,{status, ...rest}) => {
        const common = r.find(e => e.status == status)
        common ? 
        common.data.push(rest) : 
        r.push({status, data:[rest]})
        return r
      }, [])
      
console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height:100%}
```

Comment: I like your rest parameters approach, as you mentioned under my post that's for sure a better, scaled option for extra properties. I would include rest parameters documentation additionally: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce()` to achieve that:

```js
const mockResults = [{user: { firstName: '1', lastName: '1'}, status: 'WRONG'},{user: {firstName: '2',lastName: '2'},status: 'WRONG'},{user: { firstName: '3',lastName: '3'},status: 'CORRECT'}];

const result = mockResults.reduce((a, {user, status}) => {
  const temp = a.find(e => e.status === status);
  
  if (temp) {
    temp.data.push({user});
  } else {
    a.push({status, data: [{user}]});
  }
  
  return a;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Read from the [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) documentation:

> The `reduce()` method executes a reducer function (that you provide) on each element of the array, resulting in a single output value.

I hope that helps!

Comment: Turned out, my method is similar to yours, but mine is slightly better scaled ;) as it will append all extra properties, not only `user`. And I can't see anything wrong in your approach, so had to upvote to rebalance a bit :)

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov Oh, cool! I thought I may missed something out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce the array onto an object with its keys being the status property and its value an array of users with that status. Then, map over the entries to turn it back into an array of objects.

**Note:** The reduce function is creating a new object (accumulator) at each index. This is probably not practical for large data sets as it would be really slow.

```js
const toSectionList = results =>
  Object.entries(
    results.reduce(
      (obj, { user, status }) => ({
        ...obj,
        [status]: [...(obj[status] || []), { user }],
      }),
      {}
    )
  ).map(([status, data]) => ({ status, data }))

// example use:

const requiredFormat = toSectionList(mockResults)
```

The reduce function in this one modifies the accumulator object instead of creating a new one. It should preform better with larger data sets.

```js
const toSectionList = results =>
  Object.entries(
    results.reduce((obj, { user, status }) => {
      obj[status] = obj[status] || []
      obj[status].push({ user })
      return obj
    }, {})
  ).map(([status, data]) => ({ status, data }))
```

Answer (score 0):

That's what I did.

```js
const mockResults = [
  {
    user: {
      firstName: '1',
      lastName: '1'
    },
    status: 'WRONG'
  },
  {
    user: {
      firstName: '2',
      lastName: '2'
    },
    status: 'WRONG'
  },
  {
    user: {
      firstName: '3',
      lastName: '3'
    },
    status: 'CORRECT'
  }
]

function format(data) {
  const resultDict = {}
  for (let i of data) {
    if (!resultDict[i.status]) {
      resultDict[i.status] = { data: [] }
    }
    resultDict[i.status].data.push(i)
    delete resultDict[i.status].data[resultDict[i.status].data.length - 1].status
  }

  const result = []
  for (let i in resultDict) {
    const res = {
      status: i,
      data: resultDict[i].data
    }
    result.push(res)
  }

  return result
}

console.log(format(mockResults))
```